# Accidental `nano SomeFile | uniq` renders the shell unresponsive

Tags: bash, kill, freeze, nano

In my attempt to get unique entries (read lines) out of a simple text file, I accidentally executed `nano SomeTextFile | uniq`.

This "instruction" renders the shell (bash) completely (?) unresponsive/non-usable -- tested within from [Yakuake](http://yakuake.kde.org/) and [Konsole](http://konsole.kde.org/). I had to retrieve the *process id* (PID) (by executing `ps aux | grep nano`) and manually `sudo kill -9` the PID in question.

Anyhow, couldn't (or shouldn't?) the above return some error message? Why doesn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kill this pipeline? Is there an easier or cleaner way to stop it than `kill -9`?

Comment: Same thing happens with `nano xyz > abc`. Similar with `vim`

Comment: Not really sure what your question is. You could have suspended the job with `Ctrl+Z`, then `kill %1` to get rid of it...

Comment: @ire_and_curses You can't; `nano` catches SIGSTOP too

Comment: @ire_and_curses @Michael it seems, indeed, that `Ctrl+Z` and `kill %1` does something, i.e. it returns `Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM`.  Searching for the process using `ps aux | grep nano` returns `[1]+  Terminated              nano head_of_data_url_script_2012-12-17_112253.txt | uniq`. So, `Ctrl+z` is a solution, right?

Comment: I guess @cjh explained very well what happened in his answer.

Comment: @Kevin thank you for your attention to details. Yet, I don't think that my questions were too complicated or difficult to understand. Rather, as a moderate user I find the statement _kill this pipeline?_ a bit weird/not clear.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Have you tried it? The Ctrl-Z solution is effective. It works exactly as Nikos describes.

Comment: @ire_and_curses I did; SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGTSTP, and SIGTERM all failed for me (nano caught them all)

Comment: On my system, `INT` `QUIT` and `TSTP` are ignored (and C-Z), but `TERM` and `HUP` kill it with the message "Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM" (cc @MichaelMrozek)

Comment: @Michael Mrozek - Well, clearly your mileage varies. On my box, with nano 2.2.2, Ctrl-Z gives me 'Use "fg" to return to nano.' and then stops the job as expected.

Comment: @Kevin Oh, TERM does work for me, I tested it wrong apparently. C-Z is TSTP, which doesn't work. The OP was looking for a way to do it with a hotkey, and all the signals typically bound to hotkeys (INT, QUIT, TSTP) are caught for me, but apparently not everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have already explained, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't kill Nano because the input of `nano` is still coming from the terminal, and the terminal is still `nano`'s controlling terminal, so Nano is putting the terminal in raw mode where control characters such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> are transmitted to the program and not intercepted by the terminal to generate signals.

When intercepted by the terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> generates a [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29#SIGINT) signal. If you know the process ID of `nano` (you can find out with `ps u -C nano` (Linux `ps` syntax) or `pgrep nano` or other process listing utility), you can send this signal with `kill -INT 12345` where 12345 is the PID. However, SIGINT conventionally means “return to main loop”, and Nano doesn't exit when it receives SIGINT. Instead, send [SIGTERM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTERM#SIGTERM), which means “terminate gracefully”; this is the default signal, so you can just run `kill 12345`. Another possibility is `kill -HUP 12345`; [SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP#SIGHUP) means “you no longer have a terminal, quit gracefully unless you can live without”. If all else fails, send [SIGKILL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL#SIGKILL) (`kill -KILL 12345`, or famously `kill -9 12345`), which kills the program whether it wants to die or not.

Many programs, including Nano, recognize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend. This is the same sequence that sends the [SIGTSTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTSTP#SIGTSTP) signal. If the program recognizes this control key, you get back a shell prompt, and since the program becomes a background job, you can easily kill it with `kill %%` (which sends a signal to the job that has last been put into the background).

With Nano, there is [an alternate way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58951/accidental-nano-somefile-uniq-renders-the-shell-unresponsive/58959#58959): send it its exit key sequence, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed if necessary by <kbd>N</kbd> for “don't save”. But as a general matter, remember this:

1. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> followed by `kill %%`, and if this doesn't kill the program `kill -9 %%`.
2. If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> didn't work, switch to another terminal, find out the process ID (you can use `ps -t pts/42` to list the processes running on the terminal `/dev/pts/42`) and kill it.

Comment: Note that this behaviour is system-specific.  For example, in Debian console, Nano handles the SIGTSTP signal as well.

Answer (score 10):

The pipe symbol is sending the ouput of `nano` to the input of the `uniq` command.

However, `nano` is still running and receiving your keyboard input. It's just that you can't see its ouput as `uniq` won't ouput it's results until it sees an End-Of-File (this isn't important to the question).

When you press `ctrl-c` it is 'caught' by nano, but it does not cause it to exit.

**The way to exit nano is to press `ctrl-x`**, however `nano` will not exit if modifications have been made, for example, if you have pressed any other keys since entering. In this case, nano will prompt you with the following:

```
Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES) ?                                                                
 Y Yes
 N No           ^C Cancel
```

**Pressing the 'n' key will exit without saving changes.**

It is possible that you hit a few key combinations before realising you were in nano, in which case you may be a few menus deep.
Thankfully in nano pressing `ctrl-x` will also exit from most menus (but will not cancel the above prompt), this means pressing `ctrl-x` multiple times will never take you further away from the exit.

If you are 'trapped' a few menus 'deep' you can usually get out by **pressing `ctrl-x` a few times, followed by the `n` key.**  If that does not work, that means that you pressed `ctrl-x` one time too many-- just press `ctrl-x` **one** more time, followed by the `n` key-- this will always work.

Comment: Well explained. `Ctrl+Z` and `kill %1` as suggested in a comment to the initial question by @ire_and_curses is not required.

Comment: Apologies, I think @Gilles' answer deserves to be the accepted one -- so I will transfer the accepted status. Mea culpa, I should have given more time before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The shell doesn't receive you `Ctrl+C`, `nano` does.  Programs are able to define custom behavior for interrupt signals  and `nano` is one such program.  To see what the custom behavior is open `nano` without the redirection and send it a `Ctrl+C`.

Answer (score 2):

Strike `Ctrl`+`X`.

Nano captures all keyboard input and inside Nano `Ctrl`+`C` has an entirely different meaning than in the shell. If you run a `nano` in a separate window, you can easily see what keys you have to enter to exit. `Ctrl`+`X`